# How to prevent memory reallocation using std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I've read a lot of question but no one answer me for my specific case.

Actually I have

```
std::vector<Point2Dd> points;
std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
```

`Point2Dd` is a class for a 2D point, it is not important to specify how it is implemented.

Triangle however is implemented like:

```
class Triangle{
    public:
     Triangle();
     Triangle(Point2Dd* p1, Point2Dd* p2, Point2Dd* p3);
     // Getter & setter

    private:
     Point2Dd* vA = nullptr;
     Point2Dd* vB = nullptr;
     Point2Dd* vC = nullptr;
}
```

that is, as three-pointers to vector of points.

Actually it work perfectly but I've think: if I add an other point into my vector and my vector change all memory address? All my triangles will be composed by invalid address.

I've read about using `std::unique_ptr<Point2Dd>` but I don't think is the best way.

Have you any solution? 
Thanks :)

--- EDIT 1 ---

To clarify my problem I explain what problem I'm trying to solve.
I'm doing an incremental Delaunay Triangulation (no problem with that).
So I have to add once by once a point and update my triangulation.

So I've think to manage triangle as a three pointer to my points. Also I have a dag (Node -> Triangles with three children) and a structure that save adjacent triangles.

This is why I've thinked to use always a pointer, so I don't have to copy in three different structures the same points.

This is why I need to solve this problem to prevent memory reallocation.

Comment: do you really need pointers? I mean points seems to be only 2 doubles and storing a pointer instead of the `Point2Dd` saves very little memory, but adds complexity

Comment: Yes because after this I've a very heavy algorithm, so I need to optimize all as I can..

Comment: @AsoStrife I'm not sure if pointers are faster (they add indirection). Have you tried to profile?

Comment: I dont think this is an optimization. If you want to optimize memory accesses I would rather store the points directly in the triangles. The amount of memory is rarely the bottleneck, but rather the way you access it

Comment: Nope, because I use this point into other classes always as a pointer. Trust me, currently is the best way.  And the question is how to prevent the memory reallocation using pointer to this point :)

Comment: You can save indices instead of pointers plus a pointer or reference to the original vector. Those will always stay valid. (That being said, your understanding of "optimization" in this context really does sound dodgy.)

Comment: Why not shared_ptr?

Comment: @BaummitAugen they will stay valid unless the vector is rearranged (eg sorted) or elements are removed

Comment: @tobi303 Now that would mess with pointers, too.

Comment: If you definitely want to store pointers to points, you could use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`. **However, this would most likely only solve the XY-problem, not the actual issue!.**

Comment: Ok, currently storing the indexes is best idea...

Comment: Move semantics maybe? It is there to prevent memory reallocation.

Comment: @Griffin what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple options:

1. Use an `std::vector<Point*>`.  Fill it with `new` and empty it with `delete`.  Your points will live on the heap and they won't be invalidated when the vector grows.
2. Call `std::vector::reserve` with size `n` before you `push_back` the points.  `reserve` allocates space for the vector's data, so addresses won't be invalidated unless you `push_back` more than `n`points.  `std::vector::resize` could also work but check documentation first as it's slightly different.

Edit:

3. A commenter mentioned saving indices which is a great idea and probably simpler than all of this.

Comment: So if I use `std::vector<Point2Dd*> points` I can user `point.push_back(p)` without problem? The elements will never be reallocated?

Comment: @AsoStrife - It's possible that the element will be reallocated (improbable if you use `reserve()` with an adequate value) but, in this case, the elements are pointers; so the reallocation doesn't change the value of the pointers.

Comment: @AsoStrife you can do `points.push_back(new Point)`.  I can't tell if the `p` in your comment refers to a value or a pointer.  And the pointers will stay valid but may be moved around even without resize (as I think @max66 said).  If you're explicit with the types in your code, the compiler should catch most errors in this implementation E.g. `points.push_back(<point type>)` will be an error since it expect a pointer to a point.

Comment: I've solve the problem using `std;;vectir<Point2Dd*> points`. Vector will be reallocate, but the pointers are still valid.

Answer (score 6):

> Yes because after this I've a very heavy algorithm, so I need to optimize all as I can..

In this case, start with copies of data.

```
struct Triangle{
     Triangle();
     Triangle(Point2Dd p1, Point2Dd p2, Point2Dd p3);
     // Getter & setter

    private:
     Point2Dd vA, vB, vC;
};
```

Although measurement is the only way to know for sure, the loss of cache locality and the indirect memory access inherent in a pointer-based solution is almost certain to result in run times an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: But copying object is not very expansive?

Comment: @AsoStrife copying a double isnt any slower than copying a pointer

Comment: @AsoStrife making 1 copy is far quicker than indirecting a million times...

Comment: @AsoStrife To emphasize again: You are not understanding optimization correctly at all. Here is what you should do for starters: Write for correctness and clarity first, then test if it's fast enough. If it's not, find the current bottleneck(s) with a profiler and optimize those until the program runs sufficiently fast. Making random guesses about performance will most certainly end you up with slow and incorrect or at least unmaintainable code.

Comment: Ok thanks! I could try this solution or the other you suggested: "You can save indices instead of pointers plus a pointer or reference to the original vector. Those will always stay valid"

Comment: But I was think: If I do for example: triangle.getVertexA() I'll get the index not the point... So in other class I can't use the coordinates of point if I don't pass the vector of points...

Comment: @AsoStrife ...copy once... indirect never...it's the fastest way... Copying blocks of data is far more efficient that indirect access on a modern memory system. RAM is not really Random Access anymore - it's accessed in bursts of sequential access. That is hidden by the processor data cache - *if* you keep your data together. I know it's counter-intuitive, but it's true.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read about using std::unique_ptr but I don't think is the best way

And what about shared pointers ?

I mean... if your `Triangle` class contains three `std::shared_ptr<Point2Dd>`, instead of three old style pointers, and if `points` is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Point2Dd>>` instead of a vector of `Points2Dd`, you should able to write something as the following example

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Point2Dd
 { };

class Triangle
 {
   private:
      using sp2Dd = std::shared_ptr<Point2Dd>;

      sp2Dd vA, vB, vC;

   public:
      Triangle()
       { }

      Triangle (sp2Dd const & p1, sp2Dd const & p2, sp2Dd const & p3)
         : vA{p1}, vB{p2}, vC{p3}
       { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Point2Dd>> points;
   std::vector<Triangle>                  triangles;

   points.emplace_back(new Point2Dd{}); // or using std::make_shared(),
   points.emplace_back(new Point2Dd{}); // if C++14 is available
   points.emplace_back(new Point2Dd{});

   triangles.emplace_back(points[0U], points[1U], points[2U]);
 }
```

p.s.: if isn't important that all the element of `points` are stored in a unique sequential area, I suggest you to consider the use of `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`

Comment: I've tried to create a  `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Point2Dd>>` but  when I try to compile I recive this: `no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::shared_ptr<Point2D<double> >’ and ‘const Point2D<double>’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }`.
Using `points.emplace_back(new Point2Dd{x,y})`
``

Comment: @AsoStrife - you should show us a minimal example that reproduce the problem; anyway, I suppose you have something like `points[0] == Point2Dd{};`. In my example `points[0]` isn't a `Point2Dd` anymore; now it's a **pointer** (wrapped in a class, but a pointer) to a `Point2Dd`; so you have to dereference it to compare it with another pointer; something like `*points[0] == Point2Dd{};`